# Unable to create log file for some users

Tags: powershell

We have a script that runs nightly and takes all the new users from a database and makes a mailbox for them. Somehow, it doesn't like something that's inputted into the full names of employees and it's converting it to a "" for the log file. It's putting "N\A" in the file name of the log file and it can't create a file with a backslash in it.

Ignore names in the script, I've changed a lot of them to keep private information safe.

Why is this script sometimes generating a log file with a backslash in it?

Here is an example of the error

```
**Error Message**

Out-File : Could not find a part of the path '\\Server\common\Logs\New_Hire\Employee_Automated\Jesse N\A Bogdan_419772.txt'.

At \\Server\common\Folder\AppDevelopment\Powershell\SSIS_Package_Run_Scripts\Set-MailboxSettings.ps1:117

char:81

+ ... FullName) Error completing Exchange Options." | Out-File $log -Append

+                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], DirectoryNotFoundException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand

Out-File : Could not find a part of the path '\\temfs19\IT\Logs\New_Hire\Craft_Automated\Jesse N\A

Berumer_416882.txt'.

At \\Server\common\FilePath\ApplicationDevelopment\Powershell\SSIS_Package_Run_Scripts\Set-EmployeeMailboxSettings.ps1:128

char:7

+         " | Out-File $log -Append

+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], DirectoryNotFoundException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
```

**Here is the script:**

```
## Import Modules
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement

<#
#Set Office 365 Credentials
$encrypted = Get-Content C:\psscript\password.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("script@organization.com", $encrypted)
Import-Module MSOnline
$O365Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/PowerShell-LiveID?PSVersion=3.0 -Credential $Cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-PSSession $O365Session -AllowClobber
Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred
#>

## Connect to EXO using cert-based auth
Connect-ExchangeOnline -CertificateThumbPrint "cbc51f887fdc5e2l1cda672044f37f1bfda99d74" -AppID "fc6d6201-8369-417b-909d-b6f5d2d3ea5c" -Organization "organization.onmicrosoft.com" -ShowBanner:$false


## Set Variables for Script
$ServerInstance = "Server"
$DatabaseName = "Database"
$SchemaName = "dbo"
$TableName = "Org_AD_Account"

## Get Usernames
$users = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Database $DatabaseName -Query "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[v_Example_ExchDeliveryRestrictions]"

## Run for one User
#$users = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Database $DatabaseName -Query "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[v_Example_ExchDeliveryRestrictions] WHERE EmployeeNumber = '490935'"


foreach ($user in $users)
{
    try
    {
        #Get All Variables 
        $username = [string]$user.EmployeeNumber
        $Log = "\\Server\Path\Logs\New_Hire\Employee_Automated"
        $UsernameLog = ($user.FullName).replace("/", "")
        $Log = "$log\$($UsernameLog)_$($username).txt"
        
        ###############################################################################
        ## -- Start Log File
        ###############################################################################
        
        Write-Output "
********************** `r`n
Set-CraftMailboxSettings Script Start `r`n
Start Time: $(Get-Date) `r`n
********************** `r`n
###################################################################
" | Out-File $log -Append
        
        ###############################################################################
        ## -- Check if User Already has a mailbox
        ###############################################################################
        $exists = $null
        $exists = Get-Mailbox $username
        
        if ($exists)
        {
            Write-Output "[Exists] $($user.FullName) has a mailbox." | Out-File $log -Append
            
            ##Add Only allow senders in the following list
            Set-Mailbox -Identity $username -AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom @{ add = "IT" }
            
            ##Require sender authentication
            Set-Mailbox -Identity $username -RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled $true
            
            get-mailbox -Identity $username | Select-Object name, acceptmessagesonlyfrom, requiresenderauthenticationenabled | Out-File $log -Append
            
            ###############################################################################
            ## -- Mark User as complete in the database
            ###############################################################################
            Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Database $DatabaseName -Query "UPDATE [dbo].[Craft_AD_Account] SET ExchDeliveryRestrictions = 'Y', UpdateDate = GETDATE() WHERE EmployeeNumber = $($user.EmployeeNumber)"
            
        }
        else
        {
            #Check if employee number exists in AD
            $existsEmployeeNum = $null
            $existsEmployeeNum = get-aduser -SearchBase "OU=Org,DC=myorg,DC=com" -Filter * -Properties employeenumber | Where-Object {$_.employeenumber -eq $username}
            if ($existsEmployeeNum)
            {
                #This user exists with another username
                ###############################################################################
                ## -- Mark User as complete N in the database
                ###############################################################################
                Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Database $DatabaseName -Query "UPDATE [dbo].[Org_AD_Account] SET ExchDeliveryRestrictions = 'N', UpdateDate = GETDATE() WHERE EmployeeNumber = $($username)"
                
                Write-Output "[Exists] $($user.FullName) exists in AD with another username, they likely need email. No Action Required." | Out-File $log -Append
            }
            else
            {
                #This user doesn't exist with any username in AD
                Write-Output "[NOTExists] $($user.FullName) DOES NOT have a mailbox." | Out-File $log -Append
            }
            
        } #if exists
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Output "[Error] $($user.FullName) Error completing Exchange Options." | Out-File $log -Append
    } #catch
    ###############################################################################
    ## -- End Log File
    ###############################################################################
    Write-Output "
********************** `r`n
Set-CraftMailboxSettings Script END `r`n
End Time: $(Get-Date) `r`n
Script ran successfully
********************** `r`n
        " | Out-File $log -Append
} #foreach
```

I have tried to see if we even needed the script anymore because it's 3 years old now, and we thought some of our processes changed for new employees, but we still need this script.

Again, the script DOES work, but it tries to create log files for some employees with a backslash in it.

My apologies if I've done stuff out of the norm or best practices for posting here, I'm new and I'm not a programmer (I'm a sysadmin).

Thanks!

Comment: Because `N\A` *is my middle name* in AD?

Comment: Yes, but also because the log files error out because it tries to put "N/A" in the name of the log file.

Comment: "*I'm a sysadmin*" → change the `displayName` in AD. *I'm a programmer* → `$UsernameLog = ($user.FullName).replace("/", "").replace("\", "")` (in fact you should remove all [special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names))

Comment: That looks like it should work, thanks! I was kind of hoping that someone could tell me why it's even putting backslashes in the names with NA in the first place, but if I could just add that for it to stop doing it then that works.

Comment: Turns out that the data that was being used in SQL by the powershell script contained the N/As so that's where everything was coming from. Just wanted to leave this in case it's useful for anyone else.